# Once an entity is saved via put(), is any further change applied instantly to datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

There is something I didn't notice until today.

```
record3 = Record(record_date=today.date(), user=user.key)
record3.put()
record3.record_date=tomorrow.date()
record = Record.query().get()
```

I create an entity and store it in the data store. Then I change its date, but don't save it via Put().  And when I query for it from datastore, I was expecting the date to show today's date, however it already shows tomorrow's date.

Is put() using some sort of after update hook, to always update the entities after a put() has been taken place? It is quite different than traditional ORM with SQL.

**UPDATE:**
To prove my point or for sake of missing something:

```
def test_get_or_insert_updates_after_get(self):
        user = self.signup()
        today = datetime.datetime.strptime('20140405', '%Y%m%d')
        tomorrow = datetime.datetime.strptime('20140406', '%Y%m%d')
        record3 = Record(record_date=today.date(), user=user.key)
        record3.put()
        record3.record_date=tomorrow.date()
        record = Record.query().get()
        self.assertEqual(today.date(), record.record_date)
```

This unit test is failing. But why?

> AssertionError: datetime.date(2014, 4, 5) != datetime.date(2014, 4, 6)

**Solution**:
I had a bit of difficulty to understand Daniel's solution at first. This is the code sample:

```
ctx = ndb.get_context()
ctx.clear_cache()
record = Record.query().get()
```

Comment: No. That does not happen.

Comment: See updated question with unit test please

Comment: you aren't putting the entity again after setting tomorrows date.

Comment: Thats the whole point. :) I think you didn't understand the question. Solution works now. It was a cache issue as explained below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're being misled by the ndb [in-context cache](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache#incontext):

> When an NDB function writes to the Datastore, it also writes to the in-context cache. When an NDB function reads an entity, it checks the in-context cache first.

Since you're doing a direct `.get()`, rather than a query, ndb will use the in-context cache and return the *same object*. It doesn't get a new instance from the datastore, so you will see that object's local modifications. You can verify this with:

```
self.assertTrue(record is record3)
```

Alternatively, use a query, or set the context specifically to disable the cache as explained at the link above.